# Notification: limited number of request exceeded during import of delivery tickets in Freshdesk

Tags: freshdesk, invantive-sql

During import of goods deliveries from Exact Online as tickets in Freshdesk I got a message "You have exceeded the limit of request per hour".  What is the maximum number of request allowed? Is there a workaround because the batch contains all historic data (6100 records / requests) untill today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Freshdesk API rate limit guide](http://developer.freshdesk.com/api/#ratelimit) the number of calls you can make depends on the plan you are on. For example, the Sprout plan supports 1000 calls an hour, while the Forest plan allows 5000 requests.

I understand you are running an initial upload, which indeed can take a significant amount of calls to insert all items (Freshdesk supports one CREATE per call, so no chance of optimizing this). The best option you have is to insert the rows in batches. You run the first X rows now. Then another set an hour later. Even on the lowest plan you should be there in a day or so.

Another option is to contact Freshdesk support by email as suggested on their site and ask them to allow a burst of requests for a small amount of time.